# If-then statements in Python with multiple variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Working on a project that would allow for automation in Python whenever feeding new file. I need help writing that code in Jupyter Notebook. My goal is to code the following demand based on my variables in my data.

IF "Platform" 321 is down 27 "Days" THEN "MAU"  Semifluid Monitor  and A320 THSA Electric Load Sensing Device" Fits.

Essentially, I want the program to be able to look at the "Platform" and number of "Days" on the left hand side and PRINT out the multiple "MAU" that fit those requirements based on "Available for Platform" and "Days.1"

The image shows my script thus far and how my data looks.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please familiarize yourself with [help]. Also, read [ask]. Please provide *self-contained* questions, do not post links to code, or even worse, links to *images* of code. Post all code as *formatted text in the question itself*.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a `pandas` filter.

Comment: @barmar Could you be more specific on that filter idea? I'm very new to Python.